# How to load Subtitle text for Flash Video?

Tags: actionscript-3, video, subtitle, srt

A Video player is created using "Video" in flash action script 3.0. And played video using net stream. The sample code is:

```
connection = new NetConnection();
connection.connect(null);
```

on connection success stream and video crested and played.

```
stream = new NetStream(connection);
video = new Video();
video.width = stage.stageWidth;
video.height = stage.stageHeight;
video.attachNetStream(stream);

stream.play(videoURL);
```

Video is playing correctly. I want to display **subtitle** for the video. I have *.srt* formeted file for the video, any solution in as3 to load the SRT for the Video on flash.

Comment: write your own parser.

Comment: Have you looked at SRT inside Notepad? Its just text file with timecodes and relevant text. You could **[Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=nqYkUqj1Osi20QXAhoHoDQ#q=as3+srt+parser)** for an AS3 based SRT file parser or else do it yourself by just keep track of video timecode and use enterFrame to check if video_timecode == expected_SRT_Text_time (as time-coded in SRT file) and display such text..

Answer (score 1):

Writing a .srt parser isn't that difficult. Use the `CuePoint` API provided by AS3 to add cuepoints to your `Video` instance at runtime. Then listen for the `onCuePoint` event and display the relevant text in a text field.

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection(); 
nc.connect(null); 

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc); 
var client = {};
client.onCuePoint = function(info:Object):void
{
    var key:String; 
    for (key in info) 
    { 
        trace(key + ": " + info[key]); 
    }
};
ns.client = client;

var vid:Video = new Video(); 
vid.attachNetStream(ns); 
addChild(vid);
ns.play("video.flv");
```

Instead of tracing the output, you can display text in an on-screen text field.